# Can't interpolate data correctly - Angular material table - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I cannot figure out how to modify the example material data table such that I can use my own data within it...

my data appear in this format:

```
export const DATA: any = {
  'products': [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'SOLID BB T-SHIRT',
      'price': '28.00',
      ...
    },
...
]
```

From the example that Material.angular.io gives, their data is in the format:

```
export const DATA = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

However, I cannot seem to get my data format to fit the interpolation for use in the HTML as so:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I know nothing about that specific table tbh. But maybe you should pass your data as DATA.products, to be of the same type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently pointing the data source at an object, when it needs an array.  So, simple implementation might be (in .component.ts):

`dataSource = DATA["products"]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear as you did not supply code for creating `dataSource` but my guess is that you are passing `Object` instead of `Array` there. Try creating the `dataSource` with `DATA.products`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it worked for me

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
```

Then add to ngOniInit() the following

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(DATA);
}
```